# Different user experience between Android Studio and production (Google Play Store)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am stumped on this issue and how i can possibly resolve it.

Below is the screen shot of when the app is running on the physical device from Android Studio:

[image]

And then this is the same "exact" screen capture of when the app is available and downloaded and ran from the Google Play Store?!

[image]

I am really unsure how this is possible and how I can resolve it?

There is also an app crash that occurs on a different screen when dowloaded and ran from the Google Play Store which does NOT occur when ran on the physical device from Android studio.

How can I get the crash report if possible.

---

UPDATE:

---

This is what I have in the build gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
        // your project's release build type.
        minifyEnabled true

        // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
        // Android Gradle plugin.
        shrinkResources true

        // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
        // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
        // R8 configuration files.
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have minify enabled for release builds, `isMinifyEnabled = true`, over debug builds having it disabled, `isMinifyEnabled = false` in your app `build.gradle.kts` file?  You can test locally if this is the case by enabling minify for debug builds and deploying and observing behaviour.  Alternatively you can look at play console for crashes for your current deployed released app - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859174?hl=en-GB or firebase crashtylics, if added to your project - .

Comment: @Mark i have included the build gridle code. So in the release i do have it set to true. Is it suppose to be false? what is the difference?!

Comment: "what is the difference?!" - the comments in your own file tell you?  Copy/paste the entire `release { .. }` block calling it `debug { .. }` inside the `buildTypes` closure and sync. Uninstall any debug builds on the device you are testing on, then install a new debug build (green play button) - see if it exhibits the same behaviour as your playstore deployed app - we're trying to establish if this is a minify/code shrinking issue, by configuring both release/debug the same you should be able to rule out or narrow it down to this as the problem.  If so just `minifyEnabled false` and test again

Comment: @Mark it worked, i put the value to `false` and its working as designed. thx for ur help!! If you write up the solution I'll award you for the answer.

Comment: Whilst this identifies the problem, its not a complete solution.  You would identify the code minify is over "zealous" with and write exclusion rules be it your source code or a library.  Most android libraries come with proguard rules that get added when minify is enabled, but this isn't always the case. IMO if you aren't worried about code obsfucation then minify is more hassle than its worth - you may save some apk size sure, but if people are happy to install react-native and flutter apps then who cares about native apks that would in most cases always be significantly smaller anyway ..